# Unable to access variable - Out of context

Tags: c#

I've been trying to figure this out all day by searching and reading, and I know it has to be something simple, but in the last bit of code all the way at the bottom, I'm trying to create methods that print out what was entered, and I keep getting this error.

Error   CS0103  The name 'student1' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'teacher1' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'course1' does not exist in the current context

I will be forever grateful if you can just point me in the right direction or give me a hint at least.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentInformation
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do? Please choose a number: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Enter Student Information");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Enter Teacher Information");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Enter Class Information");
        Console.WriteLine();
        int menuOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (menuOne == 1)
        {
            GetStudent();
        }
        else if (menuOne == 2)
        {
            GetTeacher();
        }
        else if (menuOne == 3)
        {
            GetClass();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input. Exiting application.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


    public class Student
    {
        public string fName { get; set; }
        public string lName { get; set; }
        public string bDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public string tFName { get; set; }
        public string tLName { get; set; }
        public string tClass { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public string cName { get; set; }
        public string cSubject { get; set; }
        public string cStart { get; set; }
    }

    static void GetTeacher()
    {
        Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter teacher's first name: ");
        teacher1.tFName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter teacher's last name: ");
        teacher1.tLName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter teacher's class name: ");
        teacher1.tClass = Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void GetStudent()
    {
        Student student1 = new Student();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name: ");
        student1.fName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's last name: ");
        student1.lName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birthdate: ");
        student1.bDate = Console.ReadLine();
        PrintStudent();

    }

    static string GetClass()
    {
        Course course1 = new Course();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter class name: ");
        course1.cName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter class subject: ");
        course1.cSubject = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter class start time: ");
        course1.cStart = Console.ReadLine();
        return course1.cName;
    }

    static void PrintStudent()//Going to add PrintTeacher and PrintCourses as well after I figure this out
    {
        //string student1.fName = GetStudent();
        // Console.WriteLine(fName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}", student1.fname, teacher1.tFName, course1.cName);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: They are local variables…

Comment: this code needs clearing up.. its all over the joint!!

Comment: You should rather avoid cryptic IDs such as `fName` or `cFName`. A plain old `FirstName` will do better in both cases.

Comment: Add parameters to last function PrintStudent(Student student1, Teacher teacher1, Course course1) ...

Comment: You need to investigate [Variable Scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

All of your variables `course1`, `student1` and `teacher1` are local to the methods `GetClass`, `GetStudent` and `GetTeacher` respectively.

You need to make them class variables if you are going to access them like that. However it would be far simpler to replace your statement that writes out the details with:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}", GetStudent(), GetTeacher(), GetClass());
```

However this won't work as the "Get" methods require user input. You will need to make the variables that hold the user input into class variables.

You appear have created methods to return these values but then you're not using them, however, only the `GetClass` method returns a value. The `GetTeacher` method reads in values from the user and then does nothing with it.

Finally your `PrintStudent` method is called from `GetStudent`. If you want to use that structure then you need to pass the student name into the method:

```
static void PrintStudent(string studentName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(studentName); // Plus formatting
}
```

However, if you want to print out the class and teacher as well you are going to have to change your code structure quite radically - otherwise you could end up with infinite recursion with the print method calling the "Get" methods which call the print method ....

You need to decide how you want the code to be structured and then be consistent. Write out the logic in normal language first - this will help you identify what methods and structures you actually need. You can then turn this into pseudo code and eventually code.

Comment: he is going to have to change his getstudent method as well or you go in a endless loop!

Comment: @JoshStevens - missed that.

Comment: also there all voids so they wont return a value.

Comment: This isn't really a code question, it's more of a concept question around Variable Scope

Comment: @ChrisF your code you supplied does nothing for his task? he doesn't want to return the whole class he just wants to console log properties of that class.. i.e. name etc + his methods your calling do console logs within it so his application will run different now with your fix.